# Send image file and json to server with Retrofit 2 @Multipart

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a big JSON with many Strings and an image file.
In order to build the request

This is the imageFilePart

```
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", 
file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
```

What should I do for the body request?
Here is my interface...

```
@POST("/api/v1.0/....")
@Multipart
Call<ResponseBody> post(@Part("json_part") RequestBody 
company_name, @Part MultipartBody.Part imagefile);
```

Until now I had `(@Body MyRequest request)` but now i cannot use it when doing multipart. 
I need a way to convert **MyRequest** to RequestBody. **MyRequest** is a file with many string members.